# Load a text file to table in browser, which can be edited and then replace the origin file?

Tags: c#, blazor

This is through the Blazor Server App.

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
TEXT00
Some title
TEXT10
8
DATA
110,4,2
110,0,6
110,0,32
110,4,16
110,0,16
110,4,3
110,0,2
...
...
```

There are two things I want to accomplish:

First I want such a file be loaded on to an editable table, where the numbers under the DATA line should go in each their own editable cell.

Illustration:

| Tempo | Length | secs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 110 | 4 | 2 |
| 110 | 0 | 6 |
| 110 | 0 | 32 |

Secondly I want the content in the cells being able to be saved, such that it replaces the original text file in the directory.

With the press of a button, the file gets loaded in the a cell which is editable with the use of `contenteditable="true"`. I have tried but failed at loading the numbers into their own cells. The save file button doesn't work when it comes to data cells.

Here is the open button, table and save button:

```
<button @onclick="OpenFile">Open file</button> 
<div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-0">
        <thead class="bg-light">
            <tr>
                <th>Title: </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Tempo</th>
                <th>Length</th>
                <th>Secs</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><div contenteditable="true">@_contents</div> </td>
                <td><div contenteditable="true"></div></td>
                <td><div contenteditable="true"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div contenteditable="true"></div> </td>
                <td><div contenteditable="true"></div></td>
                <td><div contenteditable="true"></div></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<button @onclick="SaveFile">Save file</button>
```

Here are the functions which loads the file and the one which should save the new one.

```
@code {
    string _contents { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        void OpenFile()
        {
        
        _contents = File.ReadAllText(@"path");
        }

        void SaveFile()
        {
            File.WriteAllText(@"path", _contents);
        }
}
```

Does anyone have some knowledge on how to insert the numbers in cells such that when saved, the txt file gets replaced by the edits?

Comment: I want to save files to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achive this you'll need to use binding elements. For example:

```
<input @bind="YourProperty" type="text" />
```

This needs to be done for each column and every row. The best solution would look something like this:

```
List<WhateverItem> items = new(); // This list should hold all your objects from your text file

public class WhateverItem
{
    public string Tempo { get; set; }
    public string Length { get; set; }
    public string Secs { get; set; }
}
```

Then in .razor

```
@foreach (var item in items) 
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input @bind="item.Tempo" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input @bind="item.Length" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input @bind="item.Secs" type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

When you save, you'll need to recreate the content out of the objects with a StringBuilder.

If you want to validate the fields, think of using an `EditForm`. Keep in mind that you can also bind to other types besides of string. You'll need to change the input type then.

Example of parsing the file into objects:

```
List<WhateverItem> items = new();
foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"c:\test.txt"))
{
    string[] values = line.Split(',');

    if(values.Length == 3)
    {
        // Keep in mind you can also convert to values right here if you want
        items.Add(new WhateverItem
        {
            Tempo = values[0],
            Length = values[1],
            Secs = values[2]
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for asking,since I'm not sure. But how should `List<WhateverItem> items = new();` hold all objects from the file?

Comment: when i type `List<WateverItem> items = new File.ReadAllText(@"path");` i get an error at `ReadAllText` where it says it does not exist in the type File. Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: You'll need to parse the file into objects by yourself. I've put an example in my reply above.

Comment: I now have the page as the Illustration shows in the post. But I'm stuck at how to recreate the txt file with the objects that are in the cells. Can you help me?

Comment: You should have a button on the page which has an @onclick event. This event generates your new content for the text file. To generate the content I would use a StringBuilder and append each line of your List of objects to it.

Comment: I've done this `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    
    public void SaveToTxt()
    {
        foreach (var line in items)
        {
            sb.Append(items);
        }
        File.WriteLines(@"path");
    }` and `<button @onclick="SaveToTxt">Save</button>` but I'm not sure how to get the each line to the string builder, so the txt file can be overwritten.

Comment: instead of `sb.Append(items);` do: `sb.AppendLine($"{item.Tempo},{item.Length},{item.Secs}");`

Comment: When I click the `@onclick="SaveToTxt" button` nothing happens. here is the code `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    public void SaveToTxt()
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            sb.AppendLine($"{item.Tempo},{item.Length},{item.Klokke}");
        }
    }` How should it be for it to save?

Comment: You'll need to write the content to your file after the foreach loop. `File.WriteAllText(path, sb.ToString());`

Comment: If I want to have only  one cell, where all instances of tempo can be changed how would would that be accomplished?